# Expected Value of Contestant's Total Score

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I am given a practice problem but I am not really sure if I am doing this right. But I did try to attempt the problem.

> In a talent contest, there are 3 judges. The 3 contestants are to be ranked by each judge as 1st, 2nd, or 3rd. Suppose that the score by judges is random. The contestant is award points dependent on their rank by the judge. For example, Judge 1 ranks the contestant as 2nd; Judge 2 ranks the contestant as 1st; Judge 3 ranks the contestant as 2nd. The contestant's total score would be 2 + 1 + 2 = 5. Calculate the expected value of a contestant's total score.

So my attempt: I first determined that the minimum score of the contestant can be 3, and the maximum score of the contestant can be 9.

So if the three judges can choose between 1st 2nd, or 3rd equally, then they each would have a probability of 1/3.

So if for one judge, and for one contestant,

Total Score, $x_i$ $\hspace{1cm}$ $P(x_i)$

1 $\hspace{3.5cm}$ 1/3

2 $\hspace{3.5cm}$ 1/3

3 $\hspace{3.5cm}$ 1/3

Then the expected value would be
\begin{equation*}
E(X) = \sum_{i = 1}^{3} x_i P(x_i) = \dfrac{1}{3}(1 + 2 + 3) = 2
\end{equation*}
So since $E(x)$ for one judge and for one contestant is 2, then for three judges and for onecontestants would be $3 \times E(X) = 6$.

So expected value I got is 6.

Not sure if I did this right, but some help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Note that the total score awarded by all the judges is $18$ (since each of the three awards $6$).  By symmetry, each contestant must expect to get a third of that, hence $6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Since the judges assign scores to any single contestant with an identical uniform distribution over $\{1,2,3\}$, each among the $3$ scores for that contestant has an identical expectation of $2$.   So, by the Linearity of Expectation, therefore the expectation of the sum of a contestant's scores is: $6$.